# mysql group_concat not bringing entire data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query and utilizing the `group_concat` function.  However, at times the data in the `answers` column is being cut off; meaning I don't get the entire data, in the end it is just chopped off.

I suspect it might have something to do with the datatype....can it be casted to a bigger datatype? Currently the `Other1` datatype is `text`

```
 select SiteName, 
case 
when group_concat(Other1) is not null 
  then  group_concat( cast(Other1 AS BLOB)) 
when group_concat(Other1) is null
  then  'No Response provided'
end
 'answers'
from disparities_community_partnerships
where QuarterId=2
group by SiteName
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Answer (score 7):

One more sample Example
Execute like this

```
SET GLOBAL  group_concat_max_len = 5555555;
 select SiteName, 
case 
when group_concat(Other1) is not null 
  then  group_concat( cast(Other1 AS BLOB)) 
when group_concat(Other1) is null
  then  'No Response provided'
end
 'answers'
from disparities_community_partnerships
where QuarterId=2
group by SiteName
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the `group_concat_max_len` before your query:

```
SET GLOBAL  group_concat_max_len = 9999999;
```