# Incomplete output after concatenation and escaping characters

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, concatenation, group-concat

I have a string  with concatenated values done on MySQL as below:

```
CONCAT("[\"",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(concat_ws("=>",val_1, val_2,val_3)) ORDER BY val_4 DESC SEPARATOR "\",\""),"\"]")
```

I have noticed that the output of each row seems **incomplete**, from a `var_dump` it seems like that:

```
"["CONFECTIONERY=>BISCUITS=>CRACKERS",
  "CONFECTIONERY=>BISCUITS=>COOKIES",
  "ORIENTAL GROCERY=>KOREAN GROCERY=>KOREAN FOOD (DRY, PACKET)",
  "BEVERAGE=>COFFEE=>PREMIX COFFEE POWDER",
  "CLEANING AGENT & PEST CONTROL=>LAUNDRY=>LAUNDRY LIQUID",
  "CLEANING AGENT & PEST CONTROL=>LAUNDRY=>LAUNDRY POWDER",
  "BEVERAGE=>TEA=>WESTERN TEA",
  "CEREAL & SPREADS=>CEREAL=>"
```

It is missing the ending square bracket and also the third element after the => character. And also the other lines are interrupted at the same position.
If I try to `json_decode` in PHP this output I get **NULL** probably because is not well encoded, since the longest lines (more than 345 characters) are cutted.

Or maybe is a problem related to the **length** of the string? Cause I have noticed that are very long and they interrupt at the same position as characters. See the screenshot below of the output on mysqlworkbench:
[image]

I have also counted and exactly each row has **345 characters** and it breaks at the same point. It doesn't seems a coincidence:

[image]

From what I can see I should have escaped correctly the characters.
Any suggestions?

Comment: [Do you have xdebug installed?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php#82419) If so, you may need to set the `xdebug.var_display_max_data` setting.

Comment: I don't have xdebug installed. And the problem related to length limit starts when I select the data from MySQL tables in mysqlworkbench. I supposed that is not correlated to the output data displayed within PHP.

Comment: Could be a driver issue; are you checking for errors in php? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457466/5051310

Comment: I think is a limit on MySQL side probably, cause the limit length starts from there, from the SELECT.

Comment: aha: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545875/mysql-group-concat-not-bringing-entire-data

Comment: hmmmm.. it could be my case! let me check it..

Comment: If I put SET GLOBAL  group_concat_max_len = 9999999; before the selection I encounter the privileges error... it tells that I need the SUPER privileges for this operation..

Comment: that sounds like a new question (possibly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6950265/5051310)). try `SET SESSION`

Comment: @Terminus SESSION works!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its not problem with escaping or php code, it's a mysql server limitation added to grouping mechanism function, for this example group_concat.

For more information read manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

You can change this sys_option for this query or globally, but grouping that so many data on db side is a bad idea.