# Use GROUP_CONCAT query in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need the **ids** of a table but `#pluck` is not fast enough because there are too many records.
The thing is that I would like to get them in a string directly from *mysql* instead of get any *Array* or *ActiveRecord::Relation*

`[1, 2, 3] => "1,2,3"`

There is no `group_concat` in Rails, so I just asked via sql. Example:

```
sql = User.select("GROUP_CONCAT(users.id)").to_sql
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

The thing is that I don't know why but it does not return all the **ids** of the table, but just some of them.

Any idea why is not returning all of them or how can I achieve it in a different way?

Comment: Size that group_conact is limited to 1024 in mySQL.  Though it can be increased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the `group_concat_max_len`.

Maybe you could increase that value. Follow this answer to get more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545904/8195530

Answer (score 0):

You could just call it like this

```
sql = "select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from users"
data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
# #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x0000560661a2b7d8 @columns=["ids"], @rows=[["41,40,38,42,39,43,45,44"]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={}>
```

then you can get the data as ids with

```
ids = data['ids'].split(',').map(&:to_i)
# [41, 40, 38, 42, 39, 43, 45, 44]
```

Comment: Yes @Eyeslandic, that's what I did. The thing is that I don't know why but from 4614 users I only receive 263 ids. That's the problem